# Ubuntu starts to work slowly in a year

Tags: 14.04

Yesterday, I reinstalled ubuntu because it started to work slowly, with lags. And I figured that I catch myself doing the same every year or so. My ubuntu starts to work slowly in about a year.

There is definitely a pattern here.

Has anyone experienced the same?

Is there a fix for this without reinstalling the system?

`df` result:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             4085444         4   4085440   1% /dev
tmpfs             819012      1292    817720   1% /run
/dev/sda5       45047220  41445028   1290872  97% /
none                   4         0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             4095052    244364   3850688   6% /run/shm
none              102400        68    102332   1% /run/user
/dev/sda3      359194556 340096324  19098232  95% /media/jahongir/CA38409038407E07
```

`fdisk -l` result:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1baf0215

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7       HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   157571071    78682112    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       157571072   875960189   359194559    7    HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       875960318   976771071    50405377    5  Extended
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       875960320   967757823    45898752   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       967759872   976771071     4505600   82  Linux swap /     Solaris
```

I have 8GM RAM.

Comment: Are you running an SSD or HDD, do you defrag (not really necessary), and how many programs have you installed? Check the System Monitor and make sure programs aren't eating up your disk, CPU, or RAM.

Comment: What exactly is slow? Of course systems get slower over time, you can, clean out old packages, clean out /boot, remove old logs etc but the best thing is just to keep it clean and tidy IMO.

Comment: How much RAM? How much SWAP? In terminal, type `df` and edit your question with the result. In terminal, type `top`, and identify which process may be utilizing high amounts of CPU time. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema updated the question. As you said, I did `top` and stopped some services such as `mongodb` and `supervisor`. There is some improvement. Thank you.

Comment: Well, the df command shows your problem why you're running slow. **Your hard disk is full. So is your /dev/sda3**. You need to delete/uninstall/clean up in a big way. You didn't tell me how much RAM you have. I also don't see a swap?  In terminal, type `swapon`, and `sudo fdisk -l`, and tell me the results. Cheers, Al

Comment: As mentioned, your disk is nearly full, and you have not mentioned what CPU and how much RAM you have. The more things you have installed, the less disk space you have. The more things running, the less CPU/RAM are available to use. Maybe you just need to upgrade your hardware, as it seems you're reaching the limits of it with what you're doing.

Comment: @heynnema please see the update. thank you very much

Comment: Free up some space on your hard drive and you may be pleasantly surprised at how fast your computer becomes again.

Comment: I'll add my update in an answer, and you can vote/accept it if my information has helped. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discussion in the comments, I determined that there are **two major problems causing the slowness described**.

1. The two **hard disk partitions are FULL**. sda5 (root) is at 97% full. The user needs to delete old files, clean up old kernels, and uninstall unneeded applications, etc.
2. The second problem, and just as big a problem as the first, is that the extended partition (sda4) that contain his Ubuntu installation, is **not aligned properly**. This really causes some problems. **This is too big a topic to discuss here, or guide the user through fixing.** It may involve as much as **reinstalling Ubuntu** and the data all over again, **on aligned partitions** *(probably easist)*, or as little as **making adjustments to the start/end of the partitions** *(not to be taken lightly)*.

Answer (score -2):

You are right, it depends on the fact we fill the system with new files and programs.

There are some tricks you can use. But at least this two:

First, control startup applications. To view them, run the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo sed -i ‘s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g’ /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
```

Second, install preload, which helps you to better performance optimizion the loading:

```
sudo apt-get install preload
```